# ¿Cómo recorrer el siguiente arreglo en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo un código PHP el cual me trae el JSON pero no me deja recorrerlo, en este caso es `tickets`. En mi JSON me sale esto (son miles de registros más, esto es una muestra):

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "tickets": [
    "5d9c9469b2a7d12837b657b3",
    "5d9c9468b2a7d12837b657b1",
    "5d9c9459b2a7d12837b657a9",
    "5d9c9457b2a7d12837b657a7",
    "5d9c944fb2a7d12837b657a4",
    "5d9c9437b2a7d12837b6579e"]};
```

y este es mi código:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api-cluster.postcenter.io/v2/tickets/state/open',
                 CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    'Authorization: Key dksafk99w3r9',
                    "cache-control: no-cache"
                )
                );

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: para recorren un `json` debes usar `json_decode()`

Comment: Exacto. Al hacer el json_decode() me sale esto: json_decode() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given.   este es mi codigo $data =json_decode(); echo 'primer tickets: ' . $data["tickets"];

Comment: Puse eso en mi codigo y me sale ese error, pero lo otro mas curioso es que me responde con un booleano cuando hago un var_dump() de la variable $data, me responde con un 1 al final del json o me responde con true. He leido la documentación de PHP y eso es debido al curl_setop pero no se como recorrer el json sin que me de ese resultado booleano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien indica el [manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-exec.php), Para que cURL te devuelva los datos tienes que poner en `$options` un parámetro que es este: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>TRUE`, luego, puedes guardar los datos en una variable y aplicarle `json_decode`.

Intenta esto:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    $options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api-cluster.postcenter.io/v2/tickets/state/open',
                     CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> TRUE,
                     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                        'Authorization: Key dksafk99w3r9',
                        "cache-control: no-cache"
                    )
                    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $r=curl_exec($ch);

        if(!$r)
        {
            $mData=array( curl_error($ch) );

        } else {
            $json=json_decode($r);
            $mData=$json->tickets;
        }

        curl_close($ch);

    #Lectura de datos
    foreach ($mData as $item) {
        echo $item.PHP_EOL;
    }

?>
```

Si los datos vienen como muestras, verás en pantalla cada valor del array que hay en `tickets`, o bien el mensaje de error de la petición  cURL. Si no ves nada, depura la respuesta con un `var_dump($r);` y dinos lo que aparece en pantalla.

Comment: Si eso era, muchas gracias queme neuronas unos dias con esto. Me funciono crack gracias.

Comment: @YerckoOrtega Me alegro. Puedes marcarla como resulta activando la flecha gris de la izquierda y votar a favor si te parece conveniente. Saludos.

Comment: ya lo hice crack, saludos.